# number of records in box plot showing wrong

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am very new to Python. I need the number of records to be shown in each box plot as it will give the density of each month, so that the decision can be taken.

In my below boxplot the number of records for each month is not matching the original data. Could anybody tell where i am wrong?

```
order = np.sort(df760['MonthYear'].unique())
ax = sns.boxplot(x='MonthYear', y='TS', order=order, dodge=True, 
                 showfliers=True, showmeans=True,linewidth =1,
                 data=df760,palette ='gist_ncar_r')
for patch in ax.artists:
     r, g, b, a = patch.get_facecolor()
     patch.set_facecolor((r, g, b, .3))

# Calculate number of obs per group & median to position labels
means = df760.groupby(['MonthYear'])['TS'].mean().values
nobs = df760['MonthYear'].value_counts().values
nobs = [str(x) for x in nobs.tolist()]
nobs = ["n: " + i for i in nobs]
 
# Add it to the plot
pos = range(len(nobs))
for tick,label in zip(pos,ax.get_xticklabels()):
    ax.text(pos[tick], means[tick] + 0.03, nobs[tick],
            horizontalalignment='center', size='x-small', 
            color='r', weight='semibold')

ax = sns.pointplot(x='MonthYear', y='TS', order=order, data=df760, 
                   ci=None, color='#355C7D')
plt.title("760mic TS Trend")
plt.axhline(y=60, color='r', linestyle='--',linewidth = 2)
plt.axhline(y=70, color='r', linestyle='--',linewidth = 2)
plt.grid(True)
fig_size = [14,9]
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
plt.show()
```

[image: Boxplot Chart]

Here is sample of my data (you can see as for October it more than 1):

```
    MonthYear   TS
384 2020-07 61.22
385 2020-07 61.29
386 2020-07 61.56
387 2020-07 61.39
388 2020-07 62.25
389 2020-07 61.21
390 2020-07 61.84
391 2020-07 62.13
392 2020-07 61.93
393 2020-07 62.23
394 2020-07 60.00
395 2020-07 62.68
396 2020-07 67.60
397 2020-07 62.41
398 2020-07 62.00
399 2020-07 62.32
400 2020-07 61.54
401 2020-07 60.81
402 2020-07 60.80
403 2020-10 62.33
404 2020-10 62.01
405 2020-10 62.01
406 2020-10 62.01
407 2020-10 62.25
408 2020-10 62.42
409 2020-10 62.50
410 2020-10 61.98
411 2020-10 62.25
412 2020-10 62.17
413 2020-10 62.15
```

error after changing code as per answer provided:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ac362a622ff4> in <module>
      7 # Calculate number of nobs per group & median to position labels
      8 means = df760.groupby(['MonthYear'])['TS'].mean().values
----> 9 nobs = df760['MonthYear'].value_counts().reindex(means.index).values
     10 nobs = [str(x) for x in nobs.tolist()]
     11 nobs = ["n: " + i for i in nobs]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Comment: `ax.text(size='large')`If you fix it like this, the font size will be larger and the number of counts will be displayed.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. Using your sample data and plot code, the red annotated numbers do match `MonthYear` number of observations. Specifically, '2020-07' at 19 and '2020-10' at 11. Check with aggregation: `df760.groupby(['MonthYear']).size()`. Are you seeing 1 instead of 11? Increate plot `figsize`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment , i changed the definition for nobs as "df760.groupby(['MonthYear']).size()" , and now it is showing the count correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the fact that

```
means = df760.groupby(['MonthYear'])['TS'].mean().values
nobs = df760['MonthYear'].value_counts().values
```

`means` and `nobs` are not guaranteed to be in the same order. Actually, they are almost guaranteed *not* to be in the same order. [The documentation for `value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts) says

> The resulting object will be in descending order so that the first element is the most frequently-occurring element.

As you can see in your plot, the number of records goes from highest to lowest from left to right.

The solution is to force `nobs` to be in the same order as `means` by `reindex`ing

```
means = df760.groupby(['MonthYear'])['TS'].mean()
nobs = df760['MonthYear'].value_counts().reindex(means.index).values
means = means.values
```

Comment: Hi @Diziet Asahi...thank you for your answer but when i change the same ..i am getting an error ( the same has been edited in question)

Comment: Right, I've modified my answer slightly